# Error installing CyanogenMod: Unsupported bootloader

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, recovery-mode, bootloader

I am trying to install CyanogenMod 12 on my Moto G 4G XT1040 Peregrine by following [this guide](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_peregrine) from the Cyanogen Wiki.

I have:

- Unlocked my bootloader
- Installed a custom compatible recovery (TWRP v2.8.7.0)
- Downloaded the [nightly](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=peregrine) into a SD card

When I try to install the custom ROM using the recovery, I get the following error:

> This package supports bootloader(s) 0x411A; this device has bootloader
>   0x4113.

If I try to use the official Cyanogen recovery present in the image page, I get a similar error message containing the same line above.

I found [this tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/falcon-bootloader-upgrader-tool-t3093793) for upgrading the bootloader, but it's a very unofficial tool and I'm afraid to install a random bootloader found on some forum; I don't know what kind of malicious consequences it could have in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the bootloader can be upgraded using this post and tool from XDA:  [Bootloader Upgrader Tool [Falcon] [Peregrine] [41.18] [41.19] [41.1A]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/falcon-bootloader-upgrader-tool-t3093793)

Comment: it's a very unofficial tool and I'm afraid to install a random bootloader found on some forum; I don't know what kind of malicious consequences it could have in terms of security.

Comment: As an option you could flash the official Motorola lollipop rom, that should upgrade your bootloader.